# Codeigniter2, Doctrine2, Composer ect. a huge mess

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, doctrine-orm

All day I've been trying to make it work, unfortunately no success! I follow the tutorial of the doctrine home page [here](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html)

so I got composer and download all doctrine staff in a vendor folder, then I took this folder and I put it in `codeigniter/application/library` then I created a file Doctrine.php with this code:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class Doctrine {

  public $em = null; 

  public function __construct()
  { 

    include APPPATH.'config/database.php'; 
    require_once __DIR__."/Doctrine/vendor/autoload.php";

    $paths = array(APPPATH.'models/Entity');

    $isDevMode = true;

    // the connection configuration
    $dbParams = array(

        'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user'  => $db['local']['username'],
        'password'  => $db['local']['password'],
        'host'  => $db['local']['hostname'],
        'dbname'    => $db['local']['database'],
        'charset'   => $db['local']['char_set'],

    );

    $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
    $entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

    $this->em = $entityManager;

  }

}
```

And has been saved in the same path `codeigniter/application/library`

so I have a entity in my models/Entity folder which looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="site_users")
 */
class Menu
{
    //...
}
```

and the last code is in the contoller

```
$this->load->library('Doctrine');
$em = $this->doctrine->em;   
$repository = $em->getRepository('Entity\Menu');
```

and then I've got this error

```
Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class 'Entity\Menu' does not exist
```

Basically I want to use doctrine because its Gedmo tree extension, but still can install the doctrine what about the extension if someone can help it would be great thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$repository = $em->getRepository('Menu');`. You dit not push `Menu` inside a namespace, so either put it inside a namespace or use only the class name.